# WPF C#: MenuItem click event won't fire in ListView ItemContainerStyle

Tags: wpf, click, contextmenu, menuitem

I have the following XAML code in a ListView:

```
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Change" Click="ChangeStatus_Click"/>
                            <MenuItem Click="MenuItem_OnClick">
                                <MenuItem.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsActive}" Value="True">
                                                <Setter Property="Header" Value="off"/>                                                   
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsActive}" Value="False">
                                                <Setter Property="Header" Value="on"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </MenuItem.Style>
                            </MenuItem>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Why doesn't work the click event on MenuItem? Any Idea?

Comment: Do you see any errors in VS output window when you right click?

Maybe you can try instead of Click, bind Command to a command from ViewModel(DataContext) of the ListView.

Comment: No there are no errors

Comment: And if instead of Click, bind the Command property to command from your viewmodel, will that work?

Answer (score 0):

You define style for context menu so when you try add Click event handler the context menu is not already created. You will see it checking Items list in code behind.

You should use:

```
<ListView.ContextMenu>
```

Instead:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
      <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
         <Setter.Value>
```

Comment: <ListView.ContextMenu> doesn't support Styles

Comment: @sanjar14 I don't understand you. I gave you instructions on what you should change to make your code work. Why do you want to use Styles instead of ContextMenu property?

Comment: With your solution works the click event, but the toggling of the MenuItem header by the property "IsActive" does not work any more.

Comment: It work for me. You are sure that binding for property is right?